# What is your approach in testing the performance of your browser extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

We are having performance issues with our browser extension. It's an extension that injects a content script on every website visited by the user.

I've tried using performance panel on devtools and other ones available but it's hard to decipher the result of it. I'm wondering if any of you can share what your approach is.

I would appreciate if you can share how you monitor or benchmark the performance your extension where it is mainly using content scripts.

Comment: The performance panel is the correct tool, so you need to familiarize yourself with it. The question cannot be answered more specifically unless you show/describe what your extension does in much more detail.